# How to encrypt a JSON file written with jackson properly

Tags: java, json, encryption, kotlin

I'm currently working on a little Java/Kotlin program, which writes settings and some data to a JSON file.
I want to implement a functionality to encrypt this file with AES. Encrypting a file with AES is no problem at all.

Up to now I do it this way (filename is the filepath to the desired savefile from a "Save file dialog", "it" comes from the fileOutputStream.use with filename being the target, superCategory is the JSONNode to write):

```
//in the end write the stuff to the file
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(it, superCategory)

//TODO encrypt? best case: encrypt before ever writing to a file
if(encrypt) {
    //up to now I don't know how to get a stream from objectMapper instead of doint it this way
    val infile  = File(filename)
    val outfile = File(filename+"_enc")
    AESfileCrypto.doEncryption(password = password, inputFile = infile, outputFile = outfile)
    infile.delete()
}
```

AESfileCrypto is a self written class, that encrypts an input file to an output file, leaving the input file untouched.
As you might see from my comments, I don't like doing it this way at all. It seems quite vulnerable to just encrypt the file and delete the unencrypted afterwards.

I would much like to encrypt the stuff before anything gets written. Is there some way to get a
FileInputStream from the objectMapper instead to writing to a file directly? Or is there maybe a different way to write an encrypted JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the Jackson output to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then encrypt these bytes if needed, and write them to the file selected by the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try that.

Comment: Tried it, did the job. Thank you very much!